# How to use multiple threads in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multithreading, threadpool

I have single Pandas dataframe where index is the date and has different columns.
[image]

I want to access this dataframe with multiple therads. Currently I am using code as below:

[image]

When I am trying to create multiple threads using threadpool, there is no improvement in performance as i assume all multiple threads are waiting for the lock to get released in multi-threaded environment in python.

1.) is there a way where I can enhance performance using multi threading
2.) Also, is there a mechanism where I can use only column level lock in pandas dataframes

Comment: Provide you data and **full code** of a minimal reproducible example, as **text**

Answer (score 0):

1/ there are several pandas-compatible or pandas-like libraries which offer multi-threaded, multi-process or SIMD data frames. Searching SO for the [pandas and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas+multithreading) tags will show which is current, I'm not going to recommend any in particular.

2/ as asked, not without switching to one of the other libraries which allows that.  But you could yourself split your data into multiple frames and process them independently and then merge, if the data is independent enough to allow that.